# Please help me identify these seeds & Plant

Tags: identification, seeds

[image: I ordered stevia seeds online but seller sent me wrong seeds I guess.]

I ordered stevia seeds online but seller sent me wrong seeds I guess. Could someone please help me identifying these seeds. Thanks everyone.

Seeds are quite small

[image]

---

### **Edit:**

Added the pictures of the plant, please help me identify the plant

[image]
[image]

---

### **Edit (9 Oct):** Added flower and seeds pictures

[image]
[image]

Comment: How big are they (in cm)? Are they heavy? How do they smell?

Comment: Seeds are quite small actually and don't have any distinctive smell. I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess (by the look of the seeds and pictures I see online) that it's either sorghum or sugarcane, since the seeds look similar to those, and corn. If not, it's probably a relative of them (in the Poaceae family).

I've grown sorghum before. Mine had round seeds, but I see pictures of sorghum seeds that look more of a corn shape, and are the color of yours.

Comment: Thank you. I did a google search and seeds does look similar to sorghum and sugarcane.

Comment: I added pictures of the flower. Can please confirm is this sorghum?

Comment: @Sohaib It doesn't look like sorghum, but it does look a lot like sugarcane.